# intellij - cannot resolve symbol 'ericsson'

Tags: java, intellij-idea, erlang

I'm writing a program in erlang and java. I know both of them separately, but this is the first time I combine them.
I saw that I need to open the project in java, and in order to run it from erlang node I need to use this: import com.ericsson.otp.erlang.*;
But it says that it "cannot resolve symbol 'ericsson'".

Of course, I make sure that erlang is installed and working.

I'm using intellij 2020.2, erlang 23, java with open-jdk14, Ubuntu 20.04.

Got any ideas about what could be the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you have the right jars in your build path, or try do a clean build

Comment: Sorry for the lack of knowledge, but where I check this?

Comment: Have you tested this? https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206815235--Cannot-resolve-symbol-for-all-the-Java-classes

Comment: Found it! I added the path to the jar and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Could you add that as answer?